# Bootstrap Navbar positioning items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap Navbar and copied the snippet below from the site.

I am trying to position the link with class navbar-brand to the right rather than on left by default but it seems fixed?

I tried to use utility classes to float it and they do not seem to affect it.

Code Snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
     <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#speakers">Speakers</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#schedule">Schedule</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
        <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right??" href="#">Presented by Treehouse</a>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where is the code? Please post it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ml-auto` on the Brand (`navbar-brand`):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
     <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#speakers">Speakers</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#schedule">Schedule</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
        <a class="navbar-brand ml-auto" href="#">Presented by Treehouse</a>
     </div>
</nav>
```

[Working Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/N6z8puDUh4)

Alternatively, you can use `mr-auto` on the `navbar-nav` to push the brand right.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `mr-auto` class to your `navbar-brand`. That will align it to the right of other links.

**Working example**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
     <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
       <ul class="navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#speakers">Speakers</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="#schedule">Schedule</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Presented by Treehouse</a>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pull-right` on the brand.

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <a class="navbar-brand pull-right" href="#">Brand</a>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: This is for bootstrap 3..won't work for bootstrap 4 and OP is asking for B4

Comment: Thanks, but when the question was posted there was no code, and no way to tell that it was for Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Yes that's why I didn't down-voted your answer..just to let you know I added this comment.